# Responsive header displaying different parts of the image based on display size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, bootstrap-4

So, I want to create a header image for my site. I want it to be responsive and I'm taking the 'mobile first' approach. I have a picture, and as title suggest, I want it to be displayed differently based on device's display size BUT it still has to be the same image file. For example, on mobile I will see only small part of the image, but as soon as I hit certain width, it will change to full size. This site http://adopciaki.pl has exactly what I want - I tried to replicate their layout but to no avail. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

there're several possibility's to achieve this, for example, on mobile:
img{
      position: relative
      width:auto;
      height: 100%;
      left:50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
}

this will position the image centered, give the wrapper element a overflow hidden

then on tablet or desktop you can set the width to 100% and the height auto and so on...

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use an SVG copy of the image and use CSS media queries to size it based on the screen size - https://jsfiddle.net/rkr9psbf/1/

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  img { 
    width: 300px; height: 300px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  img { 
    width: 150px; height: 150px;
  }
}
```

You'll see the image shrink to half the size by making your browser window smaller. Hope this helps!